# How to check if dates in array are in range Last 365 days from today Python Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, automation

I have a list of items issued last 365 days, last 90 days, etc.
I need to check if days are in this range: today - previous 365 days, today - last 90 days.

I created a method that sorts strings with dates, but I do not know how to check the range from the current day to the last 365 days.

I want to ensure the dates are correct since I have to check them daily.

```
   def sort_date_by_last_365_days(self):
    elements = self.driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//span[@class  ="date-content"]')
    empty_list = []
    for e in elements:
        print(e.text)
    for i in elements:
        empty_list.append(i.text)

    print(empty_list)
    data = pd.DataFrame({'Date': empty_list})
    print(data)
    data['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(data['Date'])
    data.sort_values(by='Date')
    print(data)
    return FrameworkResult(status=0)
```

The method gets all dates and sorts dates.

Comment: What does the date look like?

Comment: Sorted:
0  2022-06-23
1  2022-06-23
2  2022-06-15
3  2022-06-15
4  2022-06-15
5  2022-06-15
6  2022-06-15
7  2022-06-15
8  2022-06-15
9  2022-06-15
10 2022-06-15
11 2022-06-15
12 2022-06-15
13 2022-06-13
14 2022-06-13

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from datetime import datetime
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta

date_to_check = datetime.strptime('2022-06-23', '%Y-%m-%d')
today = datetime.today()
print(date_to_check,today)
one_year_from_now = today - relativedelta(years=1)

if today >= date_to_check >= one_year_from_now:
    print('ys')
```

You can use datetime + relativedelta and check between a range like year from today and today?